# Callback after array.remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, callback

How can I execute a function after removing a value in my Array?

In my code I have something like this:

```
self.pictures.remove(this);
```

It remove correctly my item but I need to execute a function after and it do not accept callbacks...

This is what I'd like to do, but not possible...:

```
self.pictures.remove(this, function() {
    alert('Item removed');
});
```

Comment: When calling `.remove()`, execution won't continue
until remove is finished. There's no need for a callback.

Comment: can you provide jsfilldle for the same ?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: how do you know that remove() is sync?

Comment: @dandavis - I think you and I are the only ones who noticed that there is no native `[].remove()` function in JavaScript, so without seeing either the code or documentation for that function, we don't know what the function does. The answers that assume it's synchronous are *likely* to be right, but from the information given so far we just don't know. I discussed this in more detail in my answer, way down at the bottom of the page. :-)

Comment: @MichaelGeary: well, later i realized that if remove WERE async, it would already have a callback, so the naive comments are actually probably correct...

Comment: @dandavis - Indeed, it's almost certain that the OP's `.remove()` method is synchronous - the key word here being *almost*. It's good to avoid making assumptions about things and find out for certain instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.pictures.remove(this);
alert('Item removed');
```

Removing an element from an array usually isn't asynchronous, there is no need for callbacks. The 2 lines will be executed sequentially, one after another.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a callback here since the remove() function is a synchronous operation.

The need for callbacks arises when you deal with an asynchronous operation since you don't know when it will be completed

```
self.pictures.remove(this);
alert('Item removed');
```

Comment: how do you know that remove() is sync?

Answer (score 2):

Array.remove is synchronous, meaning that after the method returns the item is removed.

```
selv.pictures.remove(this);
alert('Item removed');
// do other stuff...
```

Comment: how do you know that the [].remove() is sync?

Comment: @dandavis Hmm, that's actually a good point. It might be me being used to libraries that provides it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `remove` function of `Array`

Like this:

```
(function() {
Array.prototype.remove = function(index, callback) {
    this.splice(index, 1);
    if (callback){
       callback();
    }
    return this;
};
})();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8UUaD/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays do not have a native `.remove()` method. Type this in the Chrome console on a blank page (i.e. not the page you're testing):

```
[].remove()
```

It prints:

```
TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'remove'
```

Therefore, whatever `.remove()` method you're calling, it's one that has been defined by JavaScript code in your page.

Without knowing what that code is, there's no way to know the answer to your question. Is your `.remove()` method synchronous? Is it asynchronous? What does it do? You'll need to look at the code and see.

An easy way to do this is to put a `debugger;` statement immediately before your `.remove()` call and load/exercise your page with the Chrome developer tools open. When it breaks into the debugger you can step into the `.remove()` method and see what it really does. If it steps into code that's been minified and hard to read, use the `{}` button at the bottom to pretty print the code.

Or, if this `.remove()` method is coming from a library, check the docs for that library.

For that matter, is your `self.pictures` an actual `Array` or is it some other object type that provides its own `.remove()` method?

Chances are your `.remove()` method is an ordinary synchronous function, but you won't know until you look at the actual code in your page or the docs for that function.

Comment: "there's no way to know the answer to your question" - And yet you provide one ... Well, it's rather a comment ...

Comment: @zeroflagL - Forgive me for being slow, but I don't understand what you mean. It sounds like there is something wrong with my answer. I don't know what that is, though, and I would be grateful to understand the problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: Your answer is alright per se. But if "there's no way to know the answer to your question" then why try to answer it in the first place? It's really only that clause that made me add a comment :) Feel free to ignore me.

Comment: @zeroflagL - You're taking something I said out of context. I didn't say there is no way to know the answer. I gave an easy procedure the OP can use to determine the answer. It seems pretty useful to answer a question by saying "There's not enough information here to tell you the answer, but follow these steps and you will find out the answer for yourself."